# Route traffic of a Client VPN VPC to an instance in the same VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, vpn, amazon-vpc, routetable

I have a use-case where a remote device (ie. Laptop) is connected to the AWS [Client VPN](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpn/latest/clientvpn-admin/cvpn-getting-started.html) endpoint. Client VPN endpoint has a VPC/subnet associated and I want to see the traffic generated on different ports of my laptop in my VPC.

The client (i.e. laptop) is able to connect to the VPN server and I see the bytes transferred but I am not sure how I can experience the traffic mirroring (or forwarding) on one of the instances in my VPC.

VPC's CIDR is 172.31.0.0/16 and the route table in the associated VPC already has the following rules.

172.31.0.0/16   local (non-modifyable)
0.0.0.0/0    igw-xxx

Because of this I cannot add another rule saying that route traffic destined for 172.31.0.0/16 to a specific instance in the same VPC.

Maybe I am not using the route table correctly but I am not sure if I can do this without creating an instance in another peered VPC. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible.

VPC does not support any type of either mirroring or overriding of route destinations for any address within the scope of the VPC CIDR block.

Comment: Thanks! If I want to visualize all the traffic on the client at another instance, how would the rules look like for the route table? I thought it should work with a peered VPC but it is not allowing me to add an instance from the peered VPC into the route table